# can you change iMessage settings by contacts on iPad Air?

Tags: ipad, messages

I would like to be able to get texts on my iPad running iOS 8.1.3 from some people (work contacts) and not others (Wife). Is this possible? or is it an accept all or none feature?

Comment: iMessage isn't as flexible as we'd like. I'm on my phone so data juggling isn't so easy, but check my profile for related questions

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes it is possible, although it isn't as automatic/intuitive as would be nice.

On iOS 8, it is possible to mute any message thread. What I recommend that you do is go through and mute the conversations that you do not want coming into your iPad. You will no longer receive those notifications.

To do this, simply open the conversation, tap *Details*, and turn **Do Not Disturb** on.

Perhaps, in a future version of iOS, we will be able to control these things on a per-contact-group basis.

Comment: will that still allow me to get texts from that contact on my phone? or will the setting carry over to other devises?

Comment: @peter, I tested it and don't believe that iCloud syncs that setting, so I don't think it will. I couldn't test it exhaustively, though.